# Magento 1.7 Cash On Delivery & Bank Transfer: Sufficient replacement for 3rd party extensions?

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, cash-on-delivery

Magento 1.7 brought two new core payment methods: Cash On Delivery and Bank Transfer. Until now, European stores that needed those methods had to use 3rd party extensions like [Phoenix_BankPayment](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/PHOENIX/extension/304/bank-prepayment-vorkasse-) and [Phoenix_CashOnDelivery](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/PHOENIX/extension/454/cash-on-delivery).

Both are still maintained after the release of Magento 1.7, so obviously they did not become redundant.

I am wondering if I should give the new core methods a chance and would like to read some practical experiences: are they useful and sufficient?

Comment: I do not know about the BankPayment module, but the cash on delivery extension doesn't introduce a new payment method. It just allows you to set an additional fee to orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not analyse the new core modules, but the Phoenix Media team says that the feature set is different, so that a replacement is not an option. Hence I would stick to the Phoenix Media extensions - they work flawlessly.

Source: https://twitter.com/phoenix_medien/status/321257503499382784